# How to remove faint borders around table cells only viewable in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a simple example: 2 table cells comprising a table, both table cells have a white background and the table has a black background. The width of the table is fixed and the width and height of the left table cell are fixed.

When I view the code in IE, Firefox, or Opera, I see nothing on the screen as it should be. When I view in Google Chrome, I see a faint grey outline surrounding the table cells.

This is a simple example condensed from a much more complicated example involving background images in the different cells.

It is like there is anti-aliasing occurring between the white cells and the black table in Chrome. How do I remove those outlines?

```css
#page {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 600px;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: black;
}

#leftcol {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 154px;
  height: 342px;
  background-color: white;
}

#content {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="leftcol"></div>
  <div id="content" class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add a screenshot?

Comment: I don't see anything in chrome on mac

Comment: can't reproduce your issue (added dashed `border`s for visualization) [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/92o5jrgh/)

Comment: I would recommend trying to disable all of your extensions (if you have any enabled) and see if the problem persists. If not, then re-enable each extension one at a time to see which extension may be causing the problem.

Comment: Your [MCVE (Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example)](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is not **Complete** or **Verifiable**.

Comment: This is a link to a screen shot -- http://www.koolmoves.com/temp/chrome_issue.png; I will disable extensions as suggested.

Comment: I disabled all extensions. That didn't fix the problem. If no one else is seeing the problem, then I will not be concerned about it. I use a high dpi setting and my Chrome isn't displaying as my other browsers.

Comment: I added  /high-dpi-support=1 /force-device-scale-factor=1 after C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe and the table problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

I had this but realised I had a definition it in my css style for the whole table.
I removed the definition

```
td, th {
      border: 2px solid #ddd;
      padding: 4px;
      text-align: left;
    }
```

and my grey lines disappeared.